# Move link image 5px up on hover

Tags: css, hover, onhover

How would I go about acheiving an effect similar to that on this site's portfolio page [Solid Giant](http://solidgiant.com/portfolio/), with CSS and HTML?

I had thought that just putting something like this would work:

```
a img{
    margin-top: 5px;
}

a img:hover{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

But it did not work, even if I put the :hover on the link instead of the img. I scoured his code and css but I could not for the life of me figure this out. Help please :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`position: relative` would work:

```
a img:hover{ position: relative; 
             top: -5px;}
```

note that `position: relative` reserves the space in the document flow as if the element were *not* moved. But I think in this case, that is not an issue.

Comment: +1 for the information on `position: relative`. Didn't know that.

Comment: add padding-bottom: 5px to get rid of 'flicker'

Comment: You should definitely go with [the `translate` solution, as it is hardware-accelerated via the GPU](https://web.dev/animations-guide/).

Answer (score 18):

Also see translate():

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

```
img:hover {
    -moz-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -ms-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -o-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    transform: translate(-2px, -2px)
}
```

See a similar working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/rimian/7aPvS/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use CSS/HTML5 animations: http://slides.html5rocks.com/#css-animation

you could also wrap it in another parentdiv that has position:relative set:

```
<div class="parent">
  <img class="image" />
</div>

.parent { 
    position:relative; 
}
.image { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
}
.image:hover { 
    top:-15px; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `id`

**in HTML**

```
<div id="move"> </div>
```

**in CSS**

```
#move {
position: relative;
top: 0;
transition: top ease 1s;
}
#move:hover {
top: -5px;
}
```

note: transition didn't work when I tried and if you don't use js in your code there's really no point in using `id`.

Answer (score -2):

Give the image an id:

```
<img id="imgHover" src="" />


 #imgHover:hover { margin-top: -5px; }
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have this in your html so IE knows how to work properly

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```